# connect mysql on port changes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

i use wamp localhost on port 8080 it ope php pages good but now i want to connect mysql

```
<table width="200" border="1" dir="rtl">
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>Lname</td>
    <td>Fname</td>
    <td>ID</td>
  </tr>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("learnfiles");
$query="select * from users";
$a=mysql_query($query);
while($b=mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{


     echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$b["age"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$b["city"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$b["lname"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$b["fname"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$b["id"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}
?>
```

but it has error  Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\pro\index.php on line 16
i change the port address of myadmin is
 [http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin]
how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli` instead because mysql_connect deprecated

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'DB');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, i use visual asp.net but now i want learn php i install wamp but doesn't work i change defualt port 80 to 8080 and it worked i dont know why i cant connect mysql